# How to do a refactor for if's, any ideas?

Tags: apex, refactoring

I want to make a refactor of this code, because the if's are nested and according to good practices its difficult to read, anyone has an idea?
I can't think of one :c
For me is for me it's understandable

```
 if (mappingPlatform == null || mappingPlatform.get(deal.Prod_Platform__c) == null) {
            
            pla = new DealRegistrationStructure.UIPlatform();

            // generatePlat is a void method that I create to call fields from another class
            generatePlat(contractPlat, deal, customer, platformType);
            mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c).platforms.add(pla);

            
            
            if (mappingPlatform == null) {
              mappingPlatform = new Map<String, DealRegistrationStructure.UIOpportunity>();
              mappingPlatform.put(deal.Prod_Platform__c, mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c));
              opportunityPlatformMap.put(platformType, mappingPlatform);
            } else {
              mappingPlatform.put(deal.Prod_Platform__c, mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c));
            }
```

Comment: Programming practice tips like that are usually meant to be used as guidelines, not treated as gospel. There's not enough context here to really provide much in the way of specific advice. A few things you should definitely consider is using descriptive variable names ("pla" stands out as a candidate for improvement) and being consistent with indentation and empty lines between logical units (3 lines between `mappingOpportunity.get()` and `if (mappingPlatform == null)` seems excessive).

Comment: Also, it's pretty much a given that you'd think that code you've written is readable. At least until you work on other things and haven't looked at the code for 6+ months. For what it's worth, I think this snippet is moderately readable. There are hints at things that could be improved (`mappingPlatform.put(deal.Prod_Platform__c, mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c));` appears in both the inner if and else blocks), but again, you haven't provided sufficient context to make giving specific advice feasible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to "flatten the statements". Notice how you're checking for `mappingPlatform` to be null... twice. You can switch that around a bit to be more legible. I believe the following should be equivalent to your own code, with just one if statement:

```
if(mappingPlatform == null) {
    mappingPlatform = new Map<String, DealRegistrationStructure.UIOpportunity>();
    opportunityPlatformMap.put(platformType, mappingPlatform);
}
if (mappingPlatform.get(deal.Prod_Platform__c) == null) {
    pla = new DealRegistrationStructure.UIPlatform();
    // generatePlat is a void method that I create to call fields from another class
    generatePlat(contractPlat, deal, customer, platformType);
    mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c).platforms.add(pla);
    mappingPlatform.put(deal.Prod_Platform__c, mappingOpportunity.get(oppty.Distributor__c));
    // ...
}
```

In general, if you *can* flatten an if statement, you *should*, but as the comments have noted, sometimes you simply need nested if statements. If you absolutely need them, then you can ignore the best practice. Or, you can also use a function to call that performs an if check instead, which can often make the code more legible.

Comment: thanks for that, another thing, can the function be created in the same method where the other if's are or in a separate method?

Comment: @Moon Certainly. I had a really good example of doing this in another question, but I can't seem to find it now. Regardless, using a function or two can make your code far more legible; try to aim to keep each method between 10-30 lines or so (ideally, half a screen's height on most devices). I usually aim for a hard limit of 50 lines of code, using the [One True Brace Style](https://wiki.c2.com/?OneTrueBraceStyle) for compactness. That only applies to dense code, though, queries may be longer if necessary.